# CGAffineTransformMakeScale and inserting subviews

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ipad, uiview, cgaffinetransform

After i apply  `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale,scale)` (for example scale = 3.0) to the view - it's scaling ok. But when I'm trying to programmatically insert some subview after scaling - subview also scales by 3 times - and I don't want it to be scaled. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
        // other animations goes here
        //imageView is a global variable of UIImageView with frame         
           //CGrectMake(0,0,160,240);
             imageView.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0,2.0);//CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.5);
        // other animations goes here
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSLog(@"THe imageView rect is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(imageView.frame));
        [self performSelector:@selector(addImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];


}
```

//adding subview as you needed.

```
> -(void)addImage {
>    
> 
>  CGRect rect=imageView.frame;
>       rect.origin.x=0;
>       rect.origin.y=0;
>       [imageView setFrame:rect];
>       UIImageView *imageViewTwo=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
> [UIImage=imageNamed:@"photo-4.PNG"]];
>       [imageViewTwo setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160,
> 240)];//it will be scaled two //times
> as its superview 
>       [imageView addSubview:imageViewTwo];
>       NSLog(@"the frame of the subv iew is
> %@",NSStringFromCGRect(imageViewTwo.frame));
>       [imageViewTwo release];
>        }
```

//Resolution : Subview will also be scaled , as much as the superview, so , the possible solution will be to rescale the subView to its original size. For example 
if you have scaled superview to 2.0,2.0 , add sub view with original frame as you needed, then apply CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5,0.5);, I think it will solve your problem. `enter code here`
//Also, after we apply transform, the origin also changes. We can reset it to (0,0) after transform.

Comment: Well, i tried to resize subview and something goes wrong there. The point is that i need to enlarge some view with a pinch gesture and when user releases fingers - i need to show inside enlarged view another view, with frame that is 3 times bigger than the original little view frame. I'm getting the idea that resizing frame accordingly to pinch scale would be better idea, than affine transform. Thanks a lot for the answer :)